# I want to turn off two factor sign in for Apple ID. Did not receive email option to go back to previous settings.

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I want to turn off two factor sign in for Apple ID. I do not see that I have that option this time. It used to be that I would be sent a email letting me know it was activated and it had a option to go back to previous settings. This time I did not get a email like that. I do have that I want to recieve the information from Apple all check marked.   Is it possible? How

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long ago did you enroll the account in two-factor authentication?  You may be unable to at this point.

> **Can I turn off two-factor authentication after I’ve turned it on?**
>
> If you already use two-factor authentication, you can no longer turn it off. Certain features in the latest versions of iOS and macOS require this extra level of security, which is designed to protect your information. If you recently updated your account, you can unenroll for two weeks. Just open your enrollment confirmation email and click the link to return to your previous security settings. Keep in mind, this makes your account less secure and means that you can't use features that require higher security.

[Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)